# Run a command in another cygwin window and not exit

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

From current cygwin shell, I want to run a command(say, `pwd`) in another cygwin window, I use:

`cygstart /bin/bash pwd`

It did spawn a new cygwin window but close immediately. I want the window is still opening and showing the command execution result.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with  cygstart /bin/bash " pwd ; read a ". When you are tired of the window press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could wrap this into a simple shell that waits for some input at the end of your command. 
For example, this one achieves this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=$*
tmpcmd=/tmp/cygwr.$$
echo "#!/bin/bash" > $tmpcmd
echo "$cmd" >>  $tmpcmd
echo "read line" >>  $tmpcmd

chmod +x $tmpcmd
cygstart /bin/bash $tmpcmd
rm -f $tmpcmd
```

- copy this to a file, say ~/cygwrap.sh
- chmod +x ~/cygwrap.sh
  and then invoke it, example:

  ~/cygwrap.sh pwd

Answer (score 1):

Try the -i flag to bash to make it an interactive shell, and keep it from quitting when the command is complete. `cygstart /bin/bash -i pwd`.  Without the -i, bash sees that you want to run a command and quit.

Comment: This one will only work if the command keep running in my test.Anyway glad to know.

Comment: There's no `-i` flag anymore?

Comment: I'm wondering about this, too. The `-i` flag seems to have disappeared.